# How do I do a loop in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#slideshow').crossSlide({
      sleep: 2,
      fade: 1
    }, [
      { src: 'picture1.jpg' },
      { src: 'picture2.jpg' },
    ])
  });
</script>
```

In this script, I apply a crossSlide effect to #slideshow.
However, what if I have 20 divs, and I want to apply the crossSlide effect to each div with the class "slideshow"?

How do I loop through the divs, find the ones with the class `.slideshow`, and apply the respective image to each?

**Edit: Each div has its own image that I want to show.**

Comment: $('#slideshow') selector is not looking for a class, `#` is for ID, `.` is for class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.slideshow').each(function(index,elem) {
        $(this).crossSlide({
            sleep: 2,
            fade: 1
        }, [
            { src: 'picture'+index+'A.jpg' },
            { src: 'picture'+index+'B.jpg' },
        ])
    });
});
```

You can make the image source filename a function of the current element. You might choose the filename based on the index, an attribute on that element, or something like that.

Otherwise, you have to write it out all 20 times if there's no pattern in your filenames.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) combined with an [**element selector**](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/).

```
$('div.slideshow').crossSlide
```

Then you will have to use `.each()` on the elements and get the current object using `$(this)`

Comment: But what if each div has its own image that I want to do?